# Can't register "ctrl + shift + alt + [DirectionalArrow]"

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm working in Ubuntu 20.04 in vscode and it looks like ubuntu won't let me use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>DirectionalArrow</kbd>. If I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> or any other key, it works but specifically if I try <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>DirectionalArrow</kbd> it doesn't register. Even <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>DirectionalArrow</kbd> registers.

Is there any reason why this would be? What should I do to trouble shoot further?

Answer (score 0):

Open File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts OR `ctrl+k crtl+s`

[This window will appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byqPq.png)

[select this icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEBG5.png) 
open keyboard shortcuts(JSON)

[this window will appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Uho.png)

add this to override defaults

```
    { "key": "shift+alt+"command": "editor.action.copyLinesDownAction",
                                     "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "shift+alt+"command": "editor.action.copyLinesUpAction",
                                     "when": "editorTextFocus" },
```

`shift +alt + down /up` will copy your code